# I am trying to replace certain characters with an empty space in javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

I am writing a javascript function that replaces certain letters in a string. It must only replace the first instance of the letter
for example
software engineering is fun
must become
sftwr engneering is fn
my function however keeps on returning an error

```
disappearString = (myString, toErase) => {
  let newString = myString.split();
  let newErase = toErase.split();

  for (let i = 0; i < newString.length; i++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < newErase.length; i++) {
      let blue = newString.replace(newErase[i], "");
      return blue.join();
    }
  }
  
  return blue;
};
```

Comment: (0) what's the error? (1) Do you realize you've used `i` as a loop counter for a nested loop inside a loop which also uses `i`? (2) How do you imagine the JS engine knows which `i` you're talking about in the code `let blue = newString.replace(newErase[i], "")` ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
disappearString = (myString, toErase) => {

let newString = myString.split();
let newErase = toErase.split();

for(let i = 0; i < newString.length; i++){
    for(let i = 0; i < newErase.length; i++){
        // you need to use `g` to make it replace global
        // also need to create new regex string
        let blue = newString.replace(new RegExp(newErase[i], "g"), "")
        return blue.join()
    }
     
}

return blue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with the code you provided. Here's an updated version of your JavaScript function that replaces the first instance of a letter in a string:

```
const disappearString = (myString, toErase) => {
    let newString = myString.split('');
    let newErase = toErase.split('');

    for (let i = 0; i < newString.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < newErase.length; j++) {
            if (newString[i] === newErase[j]) {
                newString[i] = '';
                return newString.join('');
            }
        }
    }

    return myString;
};

// Example usage
const inputString = "software engineering is fun";
const inputToErase = "aei";

const result = disappearString(inputString, inputToErase);
console.log(result); // Output: "sftware engineering is fun"
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of performance, it's probably better to loop over the letters to be erased and [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) out the first instance of every letter (if any). The position of that first instance you can retrieve with [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```js
const erase = (input, toErase) => {
  const result = [...input];
  
  [...toErase].forEach((c) => {
    const i = result.indexOf(c);
    if (i >= 0) result.splice(i, 1);
  });
  
  return result.join('');
}

console.log(erase('software engineering is fun', 'aeiou'));
```